# Multiply content of Integerfield

Tags: python, django, django-models, field

I wanna multiply by "*2" the content of my "stock" integerfield and put the result in other integerfield called *"cards"* and then disable the edition of this last field.

How i can reach that?

My fields are:

```
class card(models.Model):   

    def thumbnail(self):
        return '<a href="/media/%s"><img src="/media/%s" width=50px heigth=50px/></a>'%(self.imagen,self.imagen)

    thumbnail.allow_tags = True 

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=url, null=True, blank=True)
        precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, default=Decimal(0))
        stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)              
        categoria = models.ManyToManyField(categoryCard,null=True,blank=True)       
        cards = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to override the save() method of the card class.

Something like:

```
class card(models.Model):
    ...

    def save():
        if not self.pk: # It's a creation, not an update
            self.cards = self.stock * 2
            super(card, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

PS: use "Card" instead of "card" to respect the class naming convention (very useful, especially if you have variables with the same name ^^).

Comment: Great, thank you!, even so i have a last question, after put this command must I add "cards = models.IntegerField(default=0)" to reflect this field in my admin pannel or isn't necessary. Thank you again =D

Comment: Sorry I never played with admin panel :(

Comment: ok, so I can display the information of the multiplication in a template .html with this tag? {{ card.cards }}